# Can you ssh into a server given only an HTTPs address

Tags: nginx, ssh, proxy, http, squid

I have a server that I have a domain name for. The DNS redirects the address `ssh.example.com` to `https://example.com:12345/ssh/`.

Note: My server DNS needs to have a port as my server isn't accessible through the standard ports 80/443, only port: 12345 (This cannot be changed)

The connection is able to be established as I use a reverse proxy (NGINX) on that server. This allows me to redirect to any local service now that I'm in the server. I know this part works as I have another HTTP service running that I can access.

Here is what my NGINX looks like to give an example (this part works):

```
http {
  server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;

    location /ssh/ {
        proxy_pass   https://192.168.1.1:3128; # This is the part I need help with
    }
  }
}
```

From what I've researched I think I want to use a Squid Proxy to redirect to a local HTTP service to then allow me to ssh into my server? This is the part I'm not too sure about.

In the end, if possible, I would like to be able to do `ssh user@ssh.example.com` and this allows me to connect to the server. I'm looking for any guidance please.

Comment: It's time to use IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you example or maybe give a link to how IPv6 could solve this? Thank you.

Comment: The problem simply would never arise with IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are confusing OSI layers here. You are not going to be able to reuse an HTTP connection to make an SSH connection. Two completely different applications.